# Calling to lambda function in structure

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, structure

I have a structure that defines the lambda function. Below is the code for that structure

**AccumulateUtils.cpp file**

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct AccumulateUtils {
        std::function<T()> add_first = [] (T value, const T& pair) {
            return value + pair.first;
        };
};
```

In the `main()` this structure is used with `std::accumulate` to count sum of first indexes of map. Here is the code:

**main.cpp file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include "AccumulateUtils.cpp"

int main() {
    std::map<double, int> data = /*some map*/;
    AccumulateUtils<double> utils;

    std::cout << std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0, utils.add_first);

    return 0;
}
```

Сompiler gives the following errors:

> Error C2228   left of '.first' must have class/struct/union
>   Error C2664   'std::function::function(std::function
>   &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'AccumulateUtils::'
>   to 'std::nullptr_t

Why were these errors? What's wrong in the code?

Comment: *Why* does it have to be a lambda? Why can't you have a normal template-function in a namespace instead?

Comment: Why not  overloading the `operator()`

Comment: As for your current code, you don't see any problem with you declaring the `std::function` to take *no* arguments, and have the lambda take two arguments? Or to have the template type `T` mean *two* things (both a `double` *and* a `std::pair<double, int>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda function has the signature `???(T, T const &)` which is not covertible to `T()`, the signature of the `std::function`.
In addition, the lambda itself is broken, because `T` cannot be both a value and a pair of values. Something like

```
std::function<T(T, std::pair<T, T> const &)> fun = 
[](T value, std::pair<T, T> const & pair)
{
  return value + pair.first;
};
```

works but I'm not sure that is what you want to accomplish.

Comment: pair should be `std::pair<const double, int>`, ie not the same type

Comment: `std::function<T(K acc, std::pair<const K, Value> const &)>` to avoid copy/conversion of pair.